# Event driven AngularJS code, case study

Tags: angularjs

Coming back from a jQuery background I find myself having a "procedural" way of seeing this when it comes ti "in-view" interactions.

The problem is, this approach leads to ALLOT of errors and the code is not maintainable.

So I have been reading on event driven JavaScript and tried to apply this concept on AngularJS.

**For this, I thought about a user submitting a form, having two steps and resetting everything to an original state.**

This is what I came up with:  [here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RXYxBKiTIl706UNRy15v?p=info)

**1. How do you feel about this style of programming in Angular?**

**2. How would you optimize the code?**

**3. How would you do it?**

Bellow is the code:

```
<div ng-controller="TheController" ng-init="events.init()">

        <p ng-if="showName">Name: <input type="text"></p>
        <p ng-if="showAge">Age: <input type="text"></p>

        <p ng-if="showHeight">Height: <input type="text"></p>
        <p ng-if="showWeight">Weight: <input type="text"></p>

        <button ng-if="showButtonOne" ng-click="events.submittedAgeAndName()">Submit age and name</button>

        <button ng-if="showButtonTwo" ng-click="events.submittedHeightAndWright()">Submit height and weight</button>

        <p ng-if="showThankYou">Thank you for submitting!</p>

        <button ng-if="showGetEverythingBack" ng-click="events.getEverythingBack()">Get everything back!</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('TheController', function ($scope) {

            $scope.events = {
                'init': function () {
                    $scope.showName = true;
                    $scope.showAge = true;
                    $scope.showHeight = false;
                    $scope.showWeight = false;
                    $scope.showThankYou = false;
                    $scope.showButtonOne = true;
                    $scope.showButtonTwo = false;
                    $scope.showGetEverythingBack = false;
                },
                'submittedAgeAndName': function () {
                    $scope.showName = false;
                    $scope.showAge = false;
                    $scope.showHeight = true;
                    $scope.showWeight = true;
                    $scope.showThankYou = false;
                    $scope.showButtonOne = false;
                    $scope.showButtonTwo = true;
                    $scope.showGetEverythingBack = false;
                },
                'submittedHeightAndWright': function () {
                    $scope.showName = false;
                    $scope.showAge = false;
                    $scope.showHeight = false;
                    $scope.showWeight = false;
                    $scope.showThankYou = true;
                    $scope.showButtonOne = false;
                    $scope.showButtonTwo = false;
                    $scope.showGetEverythingBack = true;
                },
                'getEverythingBack': function () {
                    this.init();
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: where are the events you talking about.

Answer (score 1):

1. How do you feel about this style of programming in Angular?

   - Way too many pointless variables
   - With no purpose for all events really no function is needed, but if you do you just change the step inside like `reset` in the plunker.
2. How would you optimize the code?

   - Declarative html, data-binding, use directives, all the regular angular principles.
   - I would probably put the whole wizard in a directive, which would tuck away a lot of the template html and make the code more reusable.
3. How would you do it?

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1KXQHM2mL9BY6DqLOww?p=preview)**

```
  <div ng-switch="events.step">
     <div ng-switch-when="1"><button ng-click="events.step=2">next</button></div>
     <div ng-switch-when="2"><button ng-click="events.step=3">next</button></div>
     <div ng-switch-when="3"><button ng-click="events.reset();">back</button></div>
 </div>
```